# How to force SBT installer with JDK 1.7 to always use HTTPS protocols that are accepted by Maven?

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

There have been some topics related to the fact that Maven repositories have been changed to TLS protocols that are not used by default with JDK 1.7 (see https://blog.sonatype.com/enhancing-ssl-security-and-http/2-support-for-central for more information).

And now it is not possible to access those repositories using older JDK, like 1.7. Seemingly, we can solve it using environment variables like:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
```

But this variable seems to be ignored by SBT installing process!

On Debian 8.5 I tried to install SBT 0.13.16 using the following commands:

```
sudo echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt=0.13.16
```

And it failed with errors like:

```
Server access Error: Received fatal alert: 
protocol_version url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.16/sbt-0.13.16.pom

Server access Error: Received fatal alert: 
protocol_version url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.16/sbt-0.13.16.jar

Server access Error: Connection reset 
url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.16/ivys/ivy.xml

Server access Error: Connection reset 
url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.16/ivys/ivy.xml
```

I cannot upgrade to newer SBT nor JDK because I'm working on a legacy project that is using some deprecated features.

How to install SBT correctly and how to make all the tools (Maven, SBT, Java itself) to always honor the https.protocols setting?

Comment: Have you checked to use `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` only?

Comment: @ khmarbaise  Yes, still the same error. But I found a workaround - if I run SBT alone later, it picks up the java options, downloads the necessary Scala packages and works just fine. It seems that just the installer is broken and ignores JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.

Comment: Ok. That good. I would suggest to post this as answer for other come by.

Answer (score 0):

I came to some kind of a workaround.

Even if the apt-get install fails, you still can run `sbt` command afterwards, and this time it will pick up the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS setting and be able to download all dependencies from Maven.

It's a pity that since Maven TLS changes the Scala installer for Debian-based systems is broken if used together with older JDK.